# Dynamic content added with AngularJS click event not working on the added content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, dynamic-html

I just started on AngularJS this week for a new project, and I have to come up to speed ASAP.

One of my requirements, is to add html content dynamically and that content might have a click event on it.

So the code Angular code I have below displays a button, and when clicked, it dynamically adds another button. Clicking on the dynamically added buttons, should add another button, but I cannot get the ng-click to work on the dynamically added buttons

`<button type="button" id="btn1" ng-click="addButton()">Click Me</button>`

The working code sample is here
http://plnkr.co/edit/pTq2THCmXqw4MO3uLyi6?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.addButton = function() {
    alert("button clicked");
    var btnhtml = '<button type="button" ng-click="addButton()">Click Me</button>';
    angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append((btnhtml));
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.0"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div id="foo">
  <button type="button" id="btn1" ng-click="addButton()">Click Me
  </button>
  </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/pTq2THCmXqw4MO3uLyi6?p=preview

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$compile) {

    var btnhtml = '<button type="button" ng-click="addButton()">Click Me</button>';
    var temp = $compile(btnhtml)($scope);

    //Let's say you have element with id 'foo' in which you want to create a button
    angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(temp);

   var addButton = function(){
       alert('Yes Click working at dynamically added element');
   }

});
```

you need to add `$compile` service here, that will bind the `angular directives` like `ng-click` to your controller scope. and dont forget to add `$compile` dependency in your controller as well like below.

here is the [**plunker demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/nqpMcXNtr05w7qXGVYbz?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great help

Comment: What you mean with 'foo' ? Where you call document.getElementById('foo').append(temp)

Comment: The only complete answer, i found. Got it working without any headache, because it has a clean plunker demo as well.

Comment: I think addButton should be scoped function like $scope.addButton=function(){....}

Answer (score 1):

You could also bind the event to your new button.

```
  $scope.addButton = function() {
    alert("button clicked");
    var btnhtml = '<button type="button">Click Me</button>';
    var newButt = angular.element(btnhtml);
    newButt.bind('click', $scope.addButton);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('foo')).append(newButt);
  }
```

Updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B5cnSYbgOs0za11ufRbM?p=preview).

Comment: Just a little tidbit note: as of Angularjs 2.0, jqLite is going to no longer be part of Angular. So people may as well start using jQuery now.