# ng-click is not working if the element is generated by directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, mean

I am creating a `directive` in `angularJS` which will replace my custom element with some elements (pagination), the elements which are generated by the `directive` has `ng-click` attribute and the value of `ng-click` attribute is the function of controller but the `ng-click` is not working

The element is

```
<my-element totalCount="5"></my-element>
```

The controller is

```
.controller('AppControler',['$scope'],function($scope){
    $scope.function1 = function(value){
        console.log('in function1 value = '+value);
    }
});
```

The directive is

```
.directive('myElement',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope:{
            totalCount: '@'
        },
        template: '<ul class="pagination"></ul>`,
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.draw = function(){
                $($element).empty();
                for (var i=1; i<=$scope.totalCount; i++){
                    var link = $('<li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="function1('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>');
                    $($element).append(link);
                }
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr, controller){
            attr.$observe('totalCount', function(){
                scope.draw();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

But when I click on the `<li>` element the `function1` of `AppController` is not invoked.

**UPDATE1**

Actually my `directive` has the `isolate-scope` and if I compile the element with `$($element).append($compile(link)($scope));` then the element linked with the directive's scope but I want to compile the element with parent's scope

**UPDATE2**

I have made some changes in my-element like

```
<my-element totalCount="5" func-to-call="function1()"></my-element>
```

In directive

```
.directive('myElement',function($compile){
    return{
        ...
        ...
        scope:{
            totalCount: '@',
            funcToCall: '&'
        },
        ...
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            $scope.draw = function(){
                ....
                ....
                var link = $('<li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="function2('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>');
                $($element).append($compile(link)($scope));
                ....
                ....
            }
            $scope.function2 = function(value){
                console.log('function2 value = '+value);
                $scope.funcToCall(value);
            }
        }
        ....
        ....
    };
});
```

in this case function2 of directive scope is calling and printing the value in console but $scope.funcToCall(value) is giving the error as

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'function1' in <3>
```

**UPDATE3**

Created **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/LFgiTyG5zcSdqfkGq1qZ?p=preview)**

Comment: The parent scope is restricted in ``myElement`` directive as it has ``isolated scope`` set.  To invoke function in controller from directive, need to pass controller function to directive and refer it as scope by using ``&``  inside directive. Refer https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope. Hope this helps and if possible create a fiddle or plunker replicating this issue.

Comment: @SameerK Plunker link added please look when you click on any page number you will get the error

Comment: You missed pass value in directive call ``<my-element func-to-call="function1()" total-count="5"></my-element>``. Please see working PLUNKER at http://plnkr.co/edit/LFgiTyG5zcSdqfkGq1qZ?p=preview. I have modified the the params are passed to controller function. using reference method.

Comment: @SameerK have you checked the console log? please look, its not working, function2 is printing the value but function1 of parent scope is not called (error in console)

Comment: Not why plunker is not getting updated.  Make below changes and it will work.  ``<my-element func-to-call="function1" total-count="5"></my-element>``  and ``$scope.funcToCall()(value);``

Comment: Hey Great Thanks @SameerK I have updated the plunker, please add your solution in answer with detail, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To invoke external function (controller function) in your case from directive when directive has `isolated scope` set, need to pass the controller function to directive like below.

`<my-element func-to-call="function1" total-count="5"></my-element>`

Then this function will be available in directive as local isolated scope as

`scope: {
        totalCount: '@',
        funcToCall: '&'
      },`

Further we can have function inside directive controller to call this external function (of course there are other ways too) like

```
$scope.function2 = function(value){       
      $scope.funcToCall()(value);
    }
```

Then finally we can call $scope.function2 in directive's element like 
`var link = $('<li><a ng-click="function2('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>');`

Below is the complete directive code.

```
app.directive('myElement', function($compile){
return{
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    totalCount: '@',
    funcToCall: '&' 
  },
  template: '<ul class="pagination"></ul>',
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){

    $scope.draw = function(){
      $($element).empty();
      for (var i=1; i<$scope.totalCount; i++){
        var link = $('<li><a ng-click="function2('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>');
        $($element).append($compile(link)($scope));
      }
    }

    $scope.function2 = function(value){
      //console.log('function2 value = '+value);
      $scope.funcToCall()(value);
    }
  },
  link: function(scope, element, attr, controller){
    scope.draw();
  }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an isolated scope in your directive , to access the parent function you will need to pass that function and for that you can use "&" in your directive.

```
scope:{
    totalCount: '@',
    fnt : '&'
 }
```

bind it to ng-click  `ng-click="fnt()"`

and to pass it from the parent the element will be like this :

```
<my-element totalCount="5" fnt="parentFunction"></my-element>
```

Comment: Plunker link added please look when you click on any page number you will get the error

Comment: @Dau fixed the passing of the parent function to fnt="parentFunction" instead of fnt="parentFunction()"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) before adding it in DOM like,

```
var link = '<li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="function1('+i+');">'+i+'</a></li>';
$($element).append($compile(link)($scope));
```

This problem is similar to [Dynamic content added with AngularJS click event not working on the added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819222/dynamic-content-added-with-angularjs-click-event-not-working-on-the-added-conten)

Update: You can pass `=` control for bi-directional binding like,

```
scope: {
  control: '='
},
```

Final Updated no need to add another call `$scope.$parent.function1(value);` in your `function2 call` like,

```
$scope.function2 = function(value){
    console.log('function2 value = '+value);
    $scope.$parent.function1(value);
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/olJifFl9I8lW4uKBlyuL?p=preview)

Comment: function1 is defined in the AppController not inside the directive, If I define the function1 within directive then its working fine with $compile but its not calling the function1 of AppController

Comment: Because the directive has the isolate scope the elements linked to directive scope, but I want to link the element with parent scope

Comment: Plunker link added please look when you click on any page number you will get the error