# AngularJS : Function is not defined error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, button

I have following code in which I have to call `RemoveItem()`   function on button click , But `RemoveItem()` function not defined error is occurred

**JavaScript Code**

```
$scope.AddShoppingItems = function() {
     console.log('clicked add item');

   i++;
         var div= document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'Item : <input type="text" name="ShopItem_'+i+'"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="RemoveItem(this)">';
    document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox').appendChild(div);


    }
 $scope.RemoveItem = function(div){
 console.log('-ve clicked');
 document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox').removeChild(div.parentNode);
 i--;
 }
```

Comment: You should not be manipulating the raw DOM to begin with in Angular, you should be using Angular directives in templates to show or hide the button as needed.

Comment: so what is the exact error ? @deceze

Comment: The immediate problem is that you're trying to call an Angular scope method from plain JavaScript. The bigger problem is that your approach to this button is completely un-angularistic.

Comment: actually i want to add textbox and button dynamically by clicking on "AddItemButton"

Comment: Trivial problem if you spend 2 hours reading documentation and tutorials. In any case deceze already answered you problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply append an html element to a dom aw what you did. You need to compile the html element to your scope then only your events in scope will trigger.

Try this.

```
$scope.AddShoppingItems = function () {
    console.log('clicked add item');

    i++;
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Item : <input type="text" name="ShopItem_' + i + '"><input type="button" value="-" ng-click="RemoveItem(this)">';
    var temp = $compile(div)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox')).append(temp);

}
$scope.RemoveItem = function (div) {
    console.log('-ve clicked');
    document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox').removeChild(div.parentNode);
    i--;
}
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819222/dynamic-content-added-with-angularjs-click-event-not-working-on-the-added-conten) for more details. You cannot simply bind `onclick` event as like you did. Use `ng-click` instead

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this line

```
div.innerHTML = 'Item : <input type="text" name="ShopItem_'+i+'"> <input type="button" value="-" onclick="RemoveItem(this)">';
';
document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox').appendChild(div);
```

By

```
div.innerHTML = 'Item : <input type="text" name="ShopItem_'+i+'"><input type="button" value="-" ng-click="RemoveItem($this)">
document.getElementById('AddItemTextbox').appendChild($compile(div)($scope));
```

Comment: It will not help too. A little closer to proper solution but still not going to work because `ng-click` doesn't mean anything at all, unless compiled.